# How to search all directories and decompress .gz file?

Tags: python, gzip

I wanted to search all the directories that start with file and read .gz file in every directory.

```
import gzip

files = glob.glob('source/file*/ccs.gz')
for file in files:
    with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as f, open('file1.txt', 'w') as o:
        for line in f:
            if "Python" in line:
                print (line, file =o)
```

When I executed the script it is running and not giving me any output.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Are you sure `Python` appears in the files?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am sure

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're reopening the output file each time you open a new input file. That truncates the output file. So you only get output from the last file.

You should open the output file just once before the loop.

```
import glob
import gzip

files = glob.glob('source/file*/ccs.gz')
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as o:
    for file in files:
        with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                if "Python" in line:
                    print (line, file =o)
```

Comment: Will this take a long time to copy those lines (lines which contain Python) into a text file

Comment: No more than any other method. I would just use the shell command `zgrep Python source/file*/ccs.gz > file1.txt`

Comment: I am aware of that command.I do not want  to grep it manually so trying to write a script

Comment: I would expect this to be about as fast as grep.

Comment: I'm not sure whats happening after executing it is neither giving me error nor the result

Comment: Add some `print()` statements so you can see what it's doing.